# upload CSV file to database on Google app engine using Python

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, csv, upload

I'm a newbie in python and started learning it from about a week. I was looking into couple of tasks one of which was to upload a file (.txt or .jpg) to a bucket on GAE. I was able to solve it by following couple of tutorials online, but i'm stuck on second task.

So here's the task. i'm trying to upload a .CSV file from my local machine to the Database on Google app engine. I tried searching for solutions, but i could find only solutions pertaining to web applications. So is there a way to upload CSV file to the database instance that i have on GAE using python, is it even possible to do this? or do we have to take up any alternatives. Any working frameworks that could directly do this on git, someone used ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: GAE is a web platform. So why did the "solutions pertaining to web applications" not help?

Comment: Hi, my task is to insert the data from csv file to the database on GAE. solutions i found were trying to have a web interface to choose a csv file and then upload, which i didn't quite understand. So is there any way to do this ?, i was reading google docs and may be this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/L64wByP7GAY) can help

Comment: If you just need to do some processing, with the uploaded data and create a new file as well, use google cloud storage. You your aim is just to insert data from the uploaded csv file, blobstore will be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload your files into blobstore, using [blobstore api](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/)

Once you upload your file in blobstore, you get blobkey, then you can use blobreader, to read csv file content and store them according in your database.

Hope it helps.